# Can't use window.innerWidth with comparison operators

Tags: javascript, html, css

I try this in console:

```
if(window.innerWidth < 100) {console.log("hello")};
```

I get:

```
undefined
```

I try window.innerWidth in console and it works fine...
Why is this not working? I'm gonna replace the console.log with some code but i'm leaving it as "hello" until this works I guess

Comment: The `undefined` message is benign. It means you entered a *statement*, not an *expression*. Entering a statement does not necessarily evaluate it. If you wrap it in a self-evaluating-function-expression then that would work.

Comment: try `if(window.innerWidth < 100) {console.log("hello")} else {console.log("d'oh");}`

Comment: Use the more than operator instead of the less than one. Et voila! Your message is printed. windowWidth is larger than 100, riiiiight?

Comment: Remove the php tag, this has nothing to php

Answer (score 0):

`window.innerWidth` shows width of visible part in pixels

```
 if(window.innerWidth < 100) {console.log("hello")};
```

This code will log "hello" only if your screen less then 100 pixels wide

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you intend to implement an event, then check the following code with a more logical number than 100 for example 800

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
    if (window.innerWidth < 800){
        console.log('hello');
    }
    
});
```